# Djanogo - Python Social Auth for social media login

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am trying to use python-social-auth to have users login with their facebook or google accounts. After the user gets the google login page and logs in to their account, I have trouble redirecting back to my site.  It says

> **This site can’t be reached** 127.0.0.1 took too long to respond.

I followed the documentation: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html

The following is in **settings.py**:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   ...
   'social_django',
   ...  
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    ...
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <--
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <--
        ],
    },
 },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
) 

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email', 
'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

In the google OAuth client, under Authorized redirect URIs, I have: https://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/

Comment: Are you really running a secure (`https`) server at `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: So are you saying that my redirect url needs to http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/, instead of https://?

Comment: So i made it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/, and that still did not solve the problem